# EF - Code First - SQL Default Value getdate() gives error

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have a Priority class that has a datetime column. This column has a default value in SQL (after EF generates database and table , I changes default value of `CreatedDate` to `getdate()`). So I just want to insert into other columns of Priority but EF does not allow me and gives this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'ToDoModel' context has changed since the database was created.  Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance.  For example, the RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data.

```
public class Priority
{

    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }       
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

}

public class ToDoModel:DbContext
{

    public  ToDoModel() : base("ToDoList.ConnectionString") {           
    }

    public DbSet<Priority> Priorites { get; set; }   

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {           

        modelBuilder.Entity<Priority>().MapSingleType().ToTable("tblPriority");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Priority>().HasKey(x => x.ID); 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Priority>().Property(x => x.CreatedDate).StoreGeneratedPattern = StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed;

         base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}


 [TestMethod]
    public void CanAddPriority()
    {
        var priority = new Priority();
        priority.Color = "red";
        priority.Image = "critical.jpg";
        priority.Name = "Critical";
        db.Priorites.Add(priority);           
        db.SaveChanges();
        Assert.IsTrue(priority.ID > 0);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `OnModelCreating` method, I set `modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase` to false and now everything is workink fine.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Priority>().MapSingleType().ToTable("tblPriority");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Priority>().HasKey(x => x.ID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Priority>().Property(x => x.CreatedDate).StoreGeneratedPattern = System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreGeneratedPattern.Computed;
        modelBuilder.IncludeMetadataInDatabase = false;
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a helpful link to explain how to drop and recreate the database if the model changes. http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/04/27/DatabaseInitializersEFCodeFirstDatabaseSetInitializer.aspx

Here is a similar, and maybe helpful, question and answer here on SO... HTH
[How to manage GetDate() with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740572/how-to-manage-getdate-with-entity-framework)

Comment: I used  **Database.SetInitializer(new RecreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ToDoModel>());** . 
I got error like this. 

System.NotSupportedException: The store generated pattern 'Computed' is not supported for properties that are not of type 'timestamp'  or 'rowversion'.

I cant change default value manually and EF does not set default value too :(

Comment: @whitestream - I updated the answer with a new link, hope it helps you!

Comment: I am using `SQL Server 2005` which does not support `datetime2` type. I dont get why EF do this due to I set `StoreGeneratedPattern` to `Computed`